# ORA-28115: policy with check option violation

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am getting "ORA-28115: policy with check option violation" while executing a stored procedure.It specifically throws error on an INSERT query within the SP.With the same request body(data) and same SP,it works in other Enviornment's DB but fails in other one with this error.Can anyone point towards what all can I do to debug and solve the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely someone has created a VPD policy on this table, which (in this case) means you can only add a row that will ultimately be visible to you based on the policy assigned.

Take a look in xxx_POLICIES to see what has been created.

Docs on DBMS_RLE here https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_RLS.html